# passing data from some fragment to one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using stepper form which contain 2 fragments and I need to pass the value data from each fragments to activity and send the value through API. The problem is, value that I receive from fragment has only 1, and another was null.

This code shows how fragment A passes the data

```
@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {

    String personalName = txtNamaRegist.getText().toString();
    if(!personalName.equals("")){
        mOnFragmentPassing.sendPersonalName(personalName);
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mOnFragmentPassing = (OnFragmentPassing) getActivity();
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

This code shows how fragment B passes the data

```
@Override
public boolean onNextButtonHandler() {
    String dataNamaToko = txtNamaToko.getText().toString();
    if(!dataNamaToko.equals("")){
        mOnFragmentPassing.sendNamaToko(dataNamaToko);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        mOnFragmentPassing = (OnFragmentPassing) getActivity();
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

And this is my interface

```
public interface OnFragmentPassing {
void sendPersonalName(String personalName);
void sendNamaToko(String dataNamaToko);
}
```

And this is my activity code that receive data from fragment

```
@Override
public void sendPersonalName(String personalName) {
    mPersonalName = personalName;
}

@Override
public void sendNamaToko(String dataNamaToko) {
    mNamaToko = dataNamaToko;
}

@Override
public void onStepperCompleted() {
    showCompletedDialog();
}

protected void showCompletedDialog(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "nama "+ mPersonalName + mNamaToko, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Which data remains null? mPersonalName or mNamaToko?

Comment: I would try removing if statements and just return whatever comes from `yourView.getText().toString();` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Nik, onStepperCompleted will call when the last fragment clicked the onNextButtonHandler()

Comment: better use `!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourText)` instead of `!yourText.equals("")`

Comment: hi @TomasJablonskis it's working, thanks